# CSV data to GraphQL schema

Tags: json, graphql, graphql-js, graphene-python

I have CSV data with different headers. I do not know these headers in advance. How can I make transform this data to a GraphQL schema?

Example query:

```
csvData(supplierId: $supplierId) {
      columns {
        id
      }
      rows {
        id
        columns {
          id
          value
        }
      }
    }
```

I want to be able to query for the columns in the file, and the rows in the file.

Expected query result:

Columns: `{id: 0, value: Name} {id: 1, value: Age}, {id: 2, value: Location}`

Rows: `{id: 0, columns: {id: 0, value: Mary}}, {id: 0, columns: {id: 1, value: 21}, {id: 0, columns: {id: 2, value: NYC}}`

Example types using graphene:

```
class Columns(object):
    id: int = Int(required=True)
    value: str = String(required=True)


class Rows(object):
    id: int = Int(required=True)
    columns: Columns = Columns(required=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you don't the know the structure in advance in graphQL, you can use a list structure as a workaround.  A CSV file is a list of rows, and a row is a key value pairs.

First define the value of each cell in a structure something like this:

```
class ColumnValueType(graphene.ObjectType):
    column_name = graphene.String(required=True)  #  this is column heading
    value = graphene.String(required=True)  #  you don't know the value type you have to assume string
```

Then define your row as a list of column values

```
class RowType(graphene.ObjectType):
    row = graphene.List(ColumnValueType)
```

and CSV data as a list of rows:

```
class CSVDataType(graphene.ObjectType):
    rows = graphene.List(RowType)
```

This is all a bit clunky but something like this should be able to hold the entire contents of a CSV file.  Hopefully this points you in the right direction of how to populate a structure like this for query results.